# When I set my FSB to 400MHz in the BIOS it actually stays at 333MHz

Tags: motherboard, overclocking, intel-core2, fsb

My front side bus (FSB) is rated for a maximum of 400MHz (Rated FSB 1600MHz). In fact, it used to run at 400MHz until recently.

I'm trying to overclock my E8400 to 3.6GHz. I have done that in the past by having the FSB at 400 with a multiplier of 9.

Now, when I set the FSB to 400, the system boots as normal, but the FSB stubbornly is stuck at 333 (Rated FSB 1333). The CMOS is set to 400, I've triple-checked it. It's just the FSB isn't listening.

Is my FSB damaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused, the FSB for a E8400 is 1333mhz.

Double check all your hardware and motherboard manual to make sure you are actually using a supported configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Wil -- I'm using a supported configuration. I'm referring to the Bus Speed. Sorry for the confusion. Bus Speed 333MHz = Rated FSB 1333 and Bus Speed 400MHz = Rated FSB 1600MHz.

Comment: ARGH, you are talking about memory speed vs CPU fsb... If I was you, don't overclock! you just shorten the life and you don't gain that much!

Comment: Not about memory speed, I don't think. The FSB says one thing in BIOS, and says another in POST and in CPU-Z. That's what I'm talking about. I hear you about shortening lifespan, which is why I'm concerned my FSB might be damaged.